# expert system user input to call a function

Tags: expert-system

I'm wondering if anyone could help, i've been playing around with the online CLIPS tutorials so i kinda have the basics, i'm just trying to play around with a rule that would ask the user for a Boolean 'y' or 'n' response that would call a python function depending on the users input.

I know this has kinda been covered here: [How to get a rule activation to call a python function, using PyClips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973556/how-to-get-a-rule-activation-to-call-a-python-function-using-pyclips)

I'm just a bit confused as to where to ask for the users input and how you would call a function based on either a 'y' or 'n'.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to create an interactive PyCLIPS session [here](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/?q=node/12).  Using that as a start, here is an example of how you can call a python function, depending on the user's input:

```
import clips

def py_input_is_y():
    print 'Input is y.'

def py_input_not_y(s):
    print 'Input is not y: %s' % s

def clips_raw_input(prompt):
    return clips.String(raw_input(prompt))

clips.RegisterPythonFunction(py_input_is_y, "input-is-y")
clips.RegisterPythonFunction(py_input_not_y, "input-not-y")
clips.RegisterPythonFunction(clips_raw_input, "raw-input")

clips.Build('''
(defrule get-input
  (initial-fact)
=>
  (bind ?x (python-call raw-input "Enter y or n:"))
  (if (= (str-compare ?x "y") 0)
   then (python-call input-is-y)
   else (python-call input-not-y ?x)))
''')
```

Assuming that code is in `getinput.py`, here is example output:

```
>>> from getinput import *
>>> clips.Reset()
>>> clips.Run()
Enter y or n:y
Input is y.
1
>>> clips.Reset()
>>> clips.Run()
Enter y or n:foo
Input is not y: foo
1
```